# Steel I-beam, Steel post, framing question

Tags: framing, structural, basement-refinishing

My basement was a coverup job. I won't go into what all was wrong with it, Long story short, we are fixing it all little by little. I'm trying to add a entertainment room. I've had the waterproofing done, got the asbestos out of all my heating and cooling vents, so I'm finally ready to start.

One thing I'm trying to figure out is the wall under the steel I-beam. The Beam is 3 3/4" wide, 9 3/4" inches tall (everything in my house comes out to 1/4 or 3/4 for some reason lol) and spans the length of the house 27' 1/4" Two round posts holding it up. They are both 6" wide, with a 6" square plate up top, so it sticks out 1 inch on either side of the beam. My main Breaker panel is 12 inches away from this I-beam. Should i just eliminate the I-beam and go to the joists above it? I just don't want to loose too much room because I'm going with the double 5/8" drywall for soundproofing. The previous owner couldn't figure it out either apparently and nicely left me with some 2x4 framing, they also didn't take into account for the basement sloping (there are shims everywhere, some as much as 3") so it just doesn't work

I also want to add a door at the end of the stairs there, basically right where the post is, but that's not as important as this wall lol. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
[image: Top of stairs]

[image: Bottom stairs and steel post]

[image: Stair and post]

[image: Post in new room and breaker box]

[image: Width]

[image: Height]

Comment: ***There is no "just" to eliminating an I-Beam holding up your house.*** Your pictures fail to convey adequate context of the whole situation (lots of "zoomed in tight on this part out of context" none of "here's a picture or two of the whole thing." As a rule, you just bump out the wall to enclose the posts and beam, unless you have a huge enough desire for a wall that is featureless on both sides, in which case you bump out the whole wall to a size that encloses the posts and beam, wasting a bit more space inside (or providing more room for sound insulation, if it's a home theater job.)

Comment: I believe the code requirements for landings will prevent "a door right at the bottom of the stairs where the post is" unless you mean opening to the side, not across the stairwell.

Comment: It’s difficult to understand exactly what we’re looking at in each picture. Is that a black column on the left side of the stairway in pic #1? Is the I beam on the left side of the stairway? What is pic #3 showing? What is pic#4 showing? Is pic #5 looking up? If pic #5 is the side of the beam, where is taken?

Comment: Generally when a steel beam is supported by steel posts, there are large footings supporting the upper structural system. If you remove the steel beam and posts and support the upper structural system, it could fail because there isn’t a sufficient footing under the wall.

Comment: You can either have a 6" thick wall, or have the posts protrude: just drywall the existing framing. Same as they did with the I-beam in your last picture; they let the flange protrude. I see a pipe in the way so you're going to have to fur down the ceiling. That will let you ignore the top flange anyway, and you just let it fly off from the last fur strip into the beam (no connection).

Comment: "Should I just [ignore] the I-beam [or try to hide it with drywall]?" Up to you.

Comment: Thanks everyone and sorry for the long awaited update i forgot about this question lol! I just framed up ti the beam and it already has 1/2 inch holes spaced every 12 inches. I just used some hardened bolts and nuts. At the post i used (cant recall the name or what it was lol!) some type of wrap my dad got and wrapped the two sides of the frame around the post. I used 1x3 strips and went down to 1/4 inch drywall to box it